# How to write find-all function (with regex) in awk or sed

Tags: python, bash, sed, awk

I have bash function which run python (which return all finded regex from stdin)

```
function find-all() {
    python -c "import re
import sys
print '\n'.join(re.findall('$1', sys.stdin.read()))"
}
```

When I use this regex `find-all 'href="([^"]*)"' < index.html` it should return first group from the regex (value of href attribute from file index.html)

How can I write this in sed or awk?

Comment: The regex support in sed, awk and grep differs to the perl-like regular expressions in python. Why do you want to reimplement this using GNU utilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you use `grep -o`.

```
-o, --only-matching
       Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.
```

E.g.:

```
$ cat > foo
test test test
test
bar
baz test
$ grep -o test foo
test
test
test
test
test
```

---

**Update**

If you were extracting href attributes from html files, using a command like:

```
$ grep -o -E 'href="([^"]*)"' /usr/share/vlc/http/index.html
href="style.css"
href="iehacks.css"
href="old/"
```

You *could* extract the values by using `cut` and `sed` like this:

```
$ grep -o -E 'href="([^"]*)"' /usr/share/vlc/http/index.html| cut -f2 -d'=' | sed -e 's/"//g'
style.css
iehacks.css
old/
```

**But** you'd be better off using html/xml parsers for reliability.

Comment: It work fine but, when I use `grep -o -E 'href="([^"]*)"'` it's return the whole matched string not first group (from parentheses).

Comment: Yes, it will. You didn't mention that as a requirement. What are your requirements?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a gawk implementation (not tested with other awks): `find_all.sh`

```
awk -v "patt=$1" '
    function find_all(str, patt) {
        while (match(str, patt, a) > 0) {
            for (i=0; i in a; i++) print a[i]
            str = substr(str, RSTART+RLENGTH)
        }
    }
    $0 ~ patt {find_all($0, patt)}
' -
```

Then:

```
echo 'asdf href="href1" asdf asdf href="href2" asdfasdf
asdfasdfasdfasdf href="href3" asdfasdfasdf' | 
find_all.sh 'href="([^"]+)"'
```

outputs:

```
href="href1"
href1
href="href2"
href2
href="href3"
href3
```

Change `i=0` to `i=1` if you only want to print the captured groups.  With `i=0` you'll get output even if you have no parentheses in your pattern.